# How to pin a Rabbitmq version on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, rabbitmq, debian

I am using PackageCloud package to install Rabbitmq using Ansible. When I installed using PackageCloud, some Rabbitmq servers run version 3.8.19 and some run 3.9.1. But I am trying to pin Rabbitmq version so that all Rabbitmq servers in all environments have the same version 3.8.19.

I added a file too `/etc/apt/preferences.d/rabbitmq` with the content

```
Package: rabbitmq-server
Pin: version 1:3.8.19
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

as mentioned in RMQ documentation but it still installs the latest version 3.9.2 instead of 3.8.19.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a conditional check on the version which is present in the file you placed on the system:

```yaml
    - shell: cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/rabbitmq
      changed_when: false
      ignore_errors: true
      register: rab_version

    - shell: echo
      when: '"3.8.19" in rab_version.stdout'
```

Comment: To make it simpler, I am trying to install manually without Ansible. Even then it installs the latest version. I am following https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-packagecloud Not sure if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

After the configured the repositories you should have something like:

```sh
sudo apt-cache policy rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.9.3-1
  Version table:
     3.9.3-1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     3.9.2-1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     3.9.1-1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     3.9.0-1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.21-1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

then you can pin the version using:

```sh
sudo cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/rabbitmq
Package: rabbitmq-server
Pin: version  3.8.19-1
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

now the Candidate is the right one:

```sh
 sudo apt-cache policy rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.19-1
```

just install it and then:

```sh
rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@node0 ...
Runtime

OS PID: 18690
OS: Linux
Uptime (seconds): 15
Is under maintenance?: false
RabbitMQ version: 3.8.19
```